# Allowing whitespace in token of my antlr grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am new to antlr and am writing an antlr grammar for a DSL. I have skipped white space to handle it . But there is a case where I optionally want my grammar to pick up a particular token with might have white space.The things which I want to accomplish here in a way is

1. Token SECATTR **to have spaces** with trimmed trailing and leading spaces.That is something like
   **aa aa_aa aa.aa aa_aa aa** to be read as single token without leading space when being used in the parsing rule
   **singlerule** of sort `COUNT(aa aa_aa aa.aa aa_aa aa      )>10` .
   As of now the tree being formed is like 
   [image: The token SECATTR having spaces in lead]
2. Solve the issue of **having spaces in my parsing rules** such as for **singlerule** `COUNT (aa aa_aa aa.aa aa_aa aa)>10` throws an error due to space after **COUNT** which is like [image: single rule with spaces]
3. Avoid clumsy parsing (if achievable) of my token **SECATTR**,since it currently being parsed in the following way for **aa aa_aa aa.aa aa_aa aa**(And I think it is the root cause of all )[image: Multiple breakdown of SECATTR]

I need to handle all of these whitespaces carefully because my other parsing rule **expr** is complex and based on **singlerule** and my end goal is to have clean way of allowing tokenization of **SECATTR** to have whitespace and **all other places whitespaces to be ignored** . Please suggest me where am I going wrong and what needs to be improved.

```
grammar Test;

options {
  language = Java;
}


fragment DIVIDE : '/';
fragment PLUS : '+';
fragment MINUS : '-';
fragment STAR : '*';
fragment MOD : '%';
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';
fragment COMMA : ',';
fragment COLON : ':';
fragment LANGLEBRACKET : '<';
fragment RANGLEBRACKET : '>';
fragment EQ : '=';
fragment NOT : '!';
fragment UNDERSCORE : '_';
fragment DOT : '.';
fragment GRTRTHANEQTO : RANGLEBRACKET EQ;
fragment LESSTHANEQTO : LANGLEBRACKET EQ;
fragment NOTEQ       : NOT EQ;

WS       :           ('\t'|'\f'|'\n'|'\r'|' ')+{ $channel=HIDDEN; };

fragment A:('a'|'A');
fragment B:('b'|'B');
fragment C:('c'|'C');
fragment D:('d'|'D');
fragment E:('e'|'E');
fragment F:('f'|'F');
fragment G:('g'|'G');
fragment H:('h'|'H');
fragment I:('i'|'I');
fragment J:('j'|'J');
fragment K:('k'|'K');
fragment L:('l'|'L');
fragment M:('m'|'M');
fragment N:('n'|'N');
fragment O:('o'|'O');
fragment P:('p'|'P');
fragment Q:('q'|'Q');
fragment R:('r'|'R');
fragment S:('s'|'S');
fragment T:('t'|'T');
fragment U:('u'|'U');
fragment V:('v'|'V');
fragment W:('w'|'W');
fragment X:('x'|'X');
fragment Y:('y'|'Y');
fragment Z:('z'|'Z');


OP1   : ((C O U N T | A V G | C O U N T D I S T I N C T) 
      | C A S T) ;

OP2   : DIVIDE|PLUS|MINUS|STAR|MOD
      |LANGLEBRACKET|RANGLEBRACKET|EQ|GRTRTHANEQTO|LESSTHANEQTO|NOTEQ
      |E Q U A L S | L I K E | N O T E Q U A L S | N O T L I K E | N O T N U L L;

OP3   : ((C O R R E S P O N D I N G | A N Y)|I);
OP4   : (A N D | O R);

DIGIT    :    ('0'..'9')+;
fragment Letter   : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
fragment Space    : ' '+;
SECATTR  :Letter (Letter|UNDERSCORE|DOT|Space)+
         ;


singlerule    : SECATTR  OP2 (DIGIT|Letter)
              | OP1 LPAREN  SECATTR RPAREN OP2  (DIGIT|Letter)
              | SECATTR OP2 SECATTR
              | OP1 LPAREN SECATTR RPAREN  OP2 OP1 LPAREN SECATTR RPAREN
;
expr    :((LPAREN? singlerule RPAREN?) OP4?)+
        |((LPAREN (LPAREN singlerule RPAREN) OP4 (LPAREN singlerule RPAREN) RPAREN)+ (OP4 (LPAREN? singlerule RPAREN?))+ OP4?)+
        | (LPAREN (LPAREN singlerule RPAREN) OP4 (LPAREN singlerule RPAREN) RPAREN OP3)+;
```

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR 3 and 4 have a feature called token channels. You can send your whitespace / comments etc... to the parser on a different channel. They are in the token stream for use but not parsed by the parser.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? I am sorry I am new to ANTLR

Comment: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules#LexerRules-channel()

Comment: How do I parse SECATTR as a token ? Is there something else I can do to allow space inside SECATTR? I changed the definition of SECATTR like this (still doesn't work)

`SECATTR   : Letter DOT Letter
          | Letter Space Letter DOT Letter Space Letter
          | Letter Space Letter UNDERSCORE Letter  DOT Letter Space Letter UNDERSCORE Letter
          | Letter Space Letter UNDERSCORE Letter Space Letter DOT Letter Space Letter UNDERSCORE Letter Space Letter`

Comment: I no longer use that for doc. Please visit antlr.org